# How do I create an Image Button in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, forms, button

How would I express the following in ASP.Net, rather than HTML?

```
<input type="image" class="no-border" src="img/forms/submit_btn.png" alt="submit" name="submit" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="img/forms/submit_btn.png" CssClass="no-border" ToolTip="Submit" name="Submit" Id="SubmitImageButton" />
```